# Tricky differential equation with $\sqrt{xy}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm stuck with the following differential equation
$$y' \sqrt{xy} - y - \sqrt{xy} + x = 0.$$

First I thought it's a Bernoulli equation but is isn't. I don\t have any further ideas.

I would really appreciate any hints or tips.

Comment: [The solution](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%E2%80%99+sqrt%28xy%29+-y+-sqrt%28xy%29+%2Bx+%3D0) is hideous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write your equation in the form
$$y'-\sqrt{\frac{y^2}{xy}}-1+\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{xy}}=0$$ and now substitute $$u=\frac{y}{x}$$

Answer (score 1):

Maple provides a solution in implicit form...
$$
\ln  \left( \sqrt {xy \left( x \right) }+x \right) +3\,\ln  \left( 
\sqrt {xy \left( x \right) }-x \right) -2\,{\frac {x}{\sqrt {xy
 \left( x \right) }-x}}-2\,\ln  \left( x \right) - C_1=0
$$